# Setting consecutive new frames at a specific width from the previous frame in Emacs

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I have the following in my init.el

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (progn
      (setq initial-frame-alist
            '((tool-bar-lines . 0)
              (width . 106) ; chars
              (height . 60) ; lines
              (left . 50)
              (top . 50)))
      (setq default-frame-alist
            '((tool-bar-lines . 0)
              (width . 106)
              (height . 60)
              (left . 50)
              (top . 50))))
  (progn
    (setq initial-frame-alist '((tool-bar-lines . 0)))
    (setq default-frame-alist '((tool-bar-lines . 0)))))
```

I am new to emacs and want to know how do I make every successive new frame open (left + 10) of the previous frame.

I want to be able to visually see all frames everytime I open a new frame with `C-x 5 2`. With the current setting in `init.el` new frames overlap the previous frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easy way here is creating frames directly emacs will create the frame following the variable:

```
ELISP> initial-frame-alist
((fullscreen . maximized)
 (left-fringe . 10)
 (right-fringe . 0))
```

I have this on my init.el

```
;; Default frame size
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

I also Use fringe-mode

```
;; Turn on the left fringe
(set-fringe-mode '(10 . 0)) ;; 10px left, 0px right
```

So this is my initial setup of the emacs, then when I need a new frame I press C-x 5-2 and do not have any problem about where emacs puts that. but if you need, to create it. I recommend you to experiment with ielm (`M-x ielm`), and with the frames:

First the function for creating frames make-frame:

```
ELISP> (make-frame)
#<frame Emacs 0x1158fc150>
ELISP>
```

This will create and emacs frame exactly as the one created with C-x 5-2

Lets move this frame:

```
ELISP> (set-frame-position nil 50 50)
t
```

[image: moving frames]

Now let's investigate the make-frame function (C-h f):

> (make-frame &optional PARAMETERS)
>
> Return a newly created frame displaying the current buffer. Optional
>   argument PARAMETERS is an alist of frame parameters for the new frame.
>   Each element of PARAMETERS should have the form (NAME . VALUE), for
>   example:
>
> (name . STRING)  The frame should be named STRING.
>
> (width . NUMBER) The frame should be NUMBER characters in width. 
>   (height . NUMBER) The frame should be NUMBER text lines high.
>
> (minibuffer . t) The frame should have a minibuffer.  (minibuffer .
>   nil)  The frame should have no minibuffer.  (minibuffer . only)   The
>   frame should contain only a minibuffer.  (minibuffer . WINDOW)    The
>   frame should use WINDOW as its minibuffer window.
>
> (window-system . nil)    The frame should be displayed on a terminal
>   device.  (window-system . x)  The frame should be displayed in an X
>   window.
>
> (display . ":0")     The frame should appear on display :0.
>
> (terminal . TERMINAL)  The frame should use the terminal object
>   TERMINAL.
>
> In addition, any parameter specified in ‘default-frame-alist’, but not
>   present in PARAMETERS, is applied.
>
> Before creating the frame (via ‘frame-creation-function’), this
>   function runs the hook ‘before-make-frame-hook’.  After creating the
>   frame, it runs the hook ‘after-make-frame-functions’ with one
>   argument, the newly created frame.
>
> If a display parameter is supplied and a window-system is not, guess
>   the window-system from the display.
>
> On graphical displays, this function does not itself make the new
>   frame the selected frame.  However, the window system may select the
>   new frame according to its own rules.

We cannot find the real information here but inspecting the function, looking at the source file: we find that the frame has this parameters: `top',`left', `width',`height', `user-size' and`user-position' parameters.

So we can specify when creating the new frame this 4 things, now we are agoing to take only the position (this also depends on your window manager, pixels and how want you to put)

```
ELISP> (make-frame '((top . 100) (left . 100) (width . 100) (height . 30)))
#<frame Emacs 0x111ca8c00>
ELISP> (make-frame '((top . 50) (left . 50) (width . 100) (height . 10)))
#<frame Emacs 0x115a5ed50>
ELISP> (make-frame '((top . 100) (left . 100) (width . 100) (height . 10)))
#<frame Emacs 0x1116e77a0>
ELISP> (make-frame '((top . 150) (left . 150) (width . 100) (height . 10)))
#<frame Emacs 0x111ac5aa0>
ELISP> (make-frame '((top . 200) (left . 200) (width . 100) (height . 10)))
#<frame Emacs 0x115c32e00>
```

And you will get this:

[image: frmaes]

(lets use